# Using a MOSFET as a low current DC load

Tags: mosfet, electronic-load

I am trying to design a circuit which can simulate very low DC loads (up to 1A). For this, I was wondering if I could use an **IRF3205** (since I have a couple lying around) and keep my Vgs very close to the threshold. Implementing a loop to adjust Vgs so that the current stays constant won't be a problem.

Can I use the MOSFET like this for longer durations and be assured that it won't fail or derate severely? Say for one year where I vary the load continuously from 100mA to 1A in 50mA steps. Are MOSFETs designed to be used in such applications?

Comment: Please provide a link to the data sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the IRF3205 is a planar FET which is a good choice for operation as a current source.

Trench FETs provide lower RDSon per square mm, but function better as switches, because they can exhibit current crowding and hot spots in linear operation.

Be sure you don't exceed the safe operating area of the FET in your design (from the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a)):
[image]

And be sure to use a control loop around the device as you suggest to keep the current constant, for example something like this from the Analog Devices [LT1492 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/14923f.pdf).  If you do those two things your design will be perfectly reliable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The LT1492 example is very helpful. Just to confirm once, using the MOSFET like this does not cause any damage to the MOSFET right? The image from the datasheet is just for single pulse current draw and not for continuous. Is there a reason why the region for continuous current has not been marked?

Comment: It will not cause any damage to the MOSFET if you don't exceed any of the maximum ratings.  For the continuous current you have to make sure you don't exceed the maximum junction temperature.  So caclulate your maximum power dissipation and multiply by the thermal resistance from junction to ambient.  If that's OK then you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the MOSFET + a loop to behave as a load current as long as you are respecting all the specifications like ID, VGS, VDS, VDB, etc specifications of the MOSFET. A simple example is as follows

[image]

I have not shown the compensation needed to make the loop stable. You'll need to take care of that as well.