# Solutions for current balancing between MOSFETs in parallel

Tags: mosfet

I am designing a programmable DC load using 120W MOSFETs available at my local store. Due to its limited power rating, I am planning to have 2-3 of them connected in parallel as shown in schematics below to achieve a minimum of 300 watts.

In the LTSpice schematics attached, I simply hooked them up in parallel to the input ports (24DC) and the simulation results look okay however after doing some research online and from some great comments to my past queries on this forum I've come to realise that MOSFET gate threshold differes even between the same models due to varying temperatures. I looked up for current balancing solution to ensure Ids  on all MOSFETS is always the same but the only solution I've been able to find by far are some exotic current balancing modules from nexperia. I was wondering if I can achieve the same using basic passive/active components?

I am thinking of attached a termistor directly to chassis of each MOSFET and use Arduino to calibrate Vref for each MOSFET but I'm afraid the thermal feedback will be too slow and MOSFETs will smoke well before Arduino has change to adjust the Vref.

[image]

Edit 1:

Additional information :

1. The input reference V1 and V5 are analog inputs coming from same analog output pin of an arduino to set the current drain. Theoratically and even in the simulation, the single reference should keep all three MOSFETs balanced however other variables like junction temperature of each mosfet will change the gate voltage threshold leading to large current flowing from MOSFET/s running cooler then the rest.
2. Although the schematic only shows 2 MOSFETs, I am looking for 3 MOSFETS to run in parallel with 5A max each making total Amp rating 15A. I am trying to understand how we can ensure the current through each one of these MOSFETs is equal at all time irrespective of their junction temperatures.

MOSFET Datasheet - https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/67691.pdf

Comment: How much current are you looking to sink through the MOSFETs?

Comment: @Finbarr 15 Amp max. I know there're mosfets available in the market for this rating but I really don't want to wait for their delivery. Another reason to have this parallel config is because my electronic current sensors have a range of 0-5A (for high accuracy).

Comment: So, the schematic is not your proposal? You want something, simpler I guess? Simpler in what sense? You'll have a damn hard time saving over an op-amp and four passives. And I don't see what an Arduino could do here that an op-amp can't do orders of magnitude better. What V, I range (min/max) are you designing for?

Comment: So, 7.5 amps per MOSFET right?

Comment: @Andyaka Lets go for 3 MOSFETs in parallel with 5A rating each.

Comment: Are you controlling each MOSFET separately as in the schematic? If so I would think you wouldn't need to worry about balancing them as each would have it's own feedback loop.

Comment: Please add a link to the MOSFET data sheet in your question and add the information you are now revealing into the question. Please don't leave important information in comments.

Comment: Bear in mind the voltage across those 1 Ohm resistors will be the same as the current through them, i.e. 7.5V for two MOSFETs and 5V for three. You'll need to make sure you still have enough Vgs left to turn them fully on.

Comment: @TimWilliams Cheaper than using some fancy MOSFETs like Nexperion  BUK764R0-40E as suggested in the link (https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN11599.pdf ). The schematic i shared is what I want to use. I just want a solution to ensure current through each mosfet is equal irrespective of their junction temperature.

Comment: @Finbarr that's precisely what I am trying to achieve. 1 ohm resistor is giving me 5 Amp curren for 5V input reference. With three of them in parallel I can achieve 15A of TOTAL rating.

Comment: Well, er, I'm not sure what you wanted to accomplish with this question -- you already answered it correctly (use op-amp per transistor)! Perhaps you should rephrase this as a schematic review?

Comment: @TimWilliams The OpAmps can't compensate for change in Vth caused by change in junction temperature of the MOSFETs. Assuming one of the three MOSFEts is better connected to the heatsink, when Vref reached 4.5V (Vth for this mosfet), the coolest one will start conducting current Ids whereas the other two will switchon later. As a result, the entire 15A will flow through MOSFET 1 thus blowing up the device.

Comment: No, that won't happen because the opamps will balance the current.

Comment: The other issue is that 5A flowing through a 5 Ohm resistor will dissipate 25W of heat.

Comment: @Finbarr Sorry but which resistor are you rerferring to ? My Current sense resistor is 1 ohm and is rated for 100 Watts so dissipating 25 watts won't be a problem.

Comment: You still have to get rid of that heat, they'll need to be bolted to a big heatsink, probably with fan cooling - same for the MOSFETs.

Comment: @Finbarr - Yup, I'd already ordered a chunky heatsink and received it this morning. Looking at the surface finish I think I may not even need a fan for active cooling. As soon as I have the circuit figured out, I will start mounting the resistors and power mosfets.

Comment: Why don't you use BJTs with some decent emitter resistors? They are much easier to control in a linear application like this and are available with much more power, higher collector-emitter voltages and most likely much cheaper. They can even reach lower C-E-voltages than mosfets' D-S-voltages.

Comment: 1 Ω is pretty low for current sensing; are you sure you can't use 100 mΩ or even 10 mΩ? You'll need to adjust your op amps, but you'll waste a lot less power.

Comment: @Hearth actually it doesn't matter. The mosfet is going from maximum resistance to less resistance. In the overall load resistance visibile to DUT , this 1 ohm resistor won't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you operate MOSFETs in their linear region you have no choice but to control each one individually. Then, it boils down to analysing each MOSFET and its ability to deal with a peak of 5 amps at some undisclosed supply voltage for some undisclosed length of time. But the data sheet can tell certain things even though the MOSFET is clearly not designed for linear applications. For instance, the safe operating area from [the data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/67691.pdf): -

[image]

The above is the safe operating area for the MOSFET and note that it only gives you information for "on-times" up to 10 ms so, if you want to handle 5 amps for longer periods you have to either (a) choose a MOSFET that is capable of operating in linear applications (there are a few) or (b), make a few guesses like what I've added in colour: -

[image]

- At 5 amps for up to 100 ms, the maximum voltage across the MOSFET is limited to about 14 volts
- At 5 amps for up to 1 second, the maximum voltage across the MOSFET is limited to about 5 volts
- For up to 10 seconds you might be able to run with 1.5 volts across the MOSFET

And, if you do the power calculations for each scenario you get 70 watts, 25 watts and 7.5 watts i.e. even though the MOSFET is rated for a maximum power handling of 140 watts, you get nothing like that in the linear current-control region.

So, does the MOSFET do what you want? Only you can say.

The reason why it can't handle linear region power is because the MOSFET will suffer from extreme thermal runaway. Here's a modified version of figure 3 in the data sheet: -

[image]

- If \$V_{GS}\$ is below 5.2 volts (the zero temperature coefficient point), as the MOSFET warms it draws more drain current. You should be able to imagine where this ends and, believe me, it's rapid (hundreds of micro-seconds to a few milliseconds for some MOSFET constructions)
- If \$V_{GS}\$ is above 5.2 volts, the MOSFET will shut-down as it warms and, protect itself.

Ask yourself what likely value of \$V_{GS}\$ you will have for 5 amps of drain current: -

[image]

Comment: Nailed it. Better use BJTs for applications like this.

Comment: I don't know why they decided to remove the DC SOA curve in newer datasheets, but the originals had it, e.g. http://www.bitsavers.org/components/internationalRectifier/1982_International_Rectifier_Hexfet_Databook.pdf p.352. Whether modern production still reflects that behavior, or the -PbF or 2nd-source versions do, isn't clear; I can at least say from experience, the ones I've tested, have behaved fine.  In a design-production context, I would recommend using caution; but for a one off, it's 99% certain to be fine.

Comment: @Ariser Well, this doesn't say anything about BJTs, and exactly the same evaluation process applies to them, too. Plenty of BJTs are available with reasonable SOA at comparable ratings, but on the whole, their DC SOAs tend to be are smaller than that of comparable MOSFETs, so that it is not generically "better".  (The distinction is stronger for operation above 100 or 200V., where few if any BJTs can boast a full-power SOA, but many MOSFETs do.)

Comment: @Andy Your answer got me worried that I'll have to go back to the drawingboard so I ferociously started scanning through technical document / other comments on this form  to better understand the SOA graphs. According to a comment in this thread below, continous Vgs can be applied if proper heatshink is removing Tj from the MOSFET.   Can you confirm this? If so, I can manage with current MOSFET and big heatsink to achieve 5A . https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/658878/using-a-mosfet-as-a-low-current-dc-load

Comment: A big heatsink won't help. Once your Vgs is below the zero temperature coefficient point, thermal runaway can happen in as little as a few hundred microseconds. The thing is that you need to buy MOSFETs that are designed for linear applications because the thermal runaway is significantly reduced. Most FETs are designed for switching applications and they presume that's the application to be used.

Comment: @Prashant if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. BTW I've done probably ten or so posts on this site about it. Try searching for [spirito effect](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=spirito+effect)

Comment: @Andyaka If you don't mind I will just keep this thread open for another day. The SOA concept is still confusing me. I've check datasheets for half a dozen high power MOSFETS but the SOA suggests same limitations. Maybe I have to start fresh tomorrow with my search.

Comment: Look at figure 3 in the MOSFET data sheet you linked and ask yourself what happens to the MOSFET current when VGS is below about 5 volts i.e. as the MOSFET starts warming.

Comment: @Andyaka okay so I've spent last day or two going through my university books to brush up on mosfet theory and the concept of SOA is making sense but what I'm realising is that the industry not always follow the fundamentals. Several "stripdown" videos of professional DC loads seem to indicate that even they are using these standard MoSfets in parallel with no regard to spirits effect you mentioned probably because the ones that are designed to operate in linear cost $80 a pop compared to $6 for these standard models. ......cont

Comment: @Andyaka this however brings me back to my original question. While I am planning to built prototype board this weekend using the standard IRF mosfet and run my own real world tests, if there's anything I can do to balance 3 of these mosfets, what should I be looking for ? I've seen articles on "current balance resistors " but I can't seem to find any reference schematics/theory for it.

Comment: If you keep them each on their own seperate op-amp circuit that's the best you can do. That provides them independently with their own ability to limit to 5 amps each.